# Functions $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $|f(x) -f(y)| \le C \prod_{i=1}^n |x_i - y_i|^{\alpha_i}$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, metric-spaces, continuity, uniform-continuity

The standard definition of a Holder continuous function between metric spaces $X,Y$ is a function $f: X \to Y$ such that there exist $C>0$ and $0 < \alpha \le 1$ such that
$$
d_Y(f(x),f(y)) \le C (d_X(x,y))^\alpha \text{ for all }x,y \in X.
$$
When specialized to $X= \mathbb{R}^n$ and $Y = \mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$ this reads
$$
|f(x)-f(y)| \le C |x-y|^\alpha \text{ for all }x,y \in \mathbb{R}^n.
$$
It is a simple matter to find examples of such functions, with the easiest case being when $\alpha =1$, as in this case any differentiable function with bounded derivative will obey the $\alpha =1$ (Lipschitz) estimate.

I was recently looking at *Classical Fourier Analysis* by Grafakos.  In the study of pointwise convergence of Fourier series he proves a result (Corollary 3.3.8) that says that if we have a function on the $n-$torus, $f: \mathbb{T}^n \to \mathbb{C}$, and a point $y \in \mathbb{T}^n$ such that
$$
|f(x) - f(y)| \le C \prod_{i=1}^n |x_i - y_i|^{\alpha_j} \text{ for all }x \in \mathbb{T}^m
$$
then the Fourier partial sums converge at $y$.  This suggests that the collection of functions satisfying this condition is of some interest.

It's not hard to build a function that satisfies this condition at a point.  To make things simpler let's swap to $\mathbb{R}^n$ from the torus and restrict to real-valued functions.  Then we can define $f(x) = \prod_{i=1}^n |x_i|^{\alpha_i}$ to get a trivial example satisfying the condition at $y=0$.  I then started thinking about this condition as a general one, satisfied for all pairs of points $x,y$, i.e. I want a function $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ such that there exist $C>0$ and $0 < \alpha_i \le 1$ such that 
$$
|f(x) - f(y)| \le C \prod_{j=1}^n |x_i - y_i|^{\alpha_i} \text{ for all }x,y \in \mathbb{R}^n.
$$
This is a sort of strange variant of the standard Holder continuity condition.  Note that to avoid triviality we should assume that $\sum_i \alpha_i \le 1$ as otherwise 
$$
|f(x)-f(y)| \le C |x-y|^{1+\epsilon} 
$$
for $\epsilon = \sum_{i} \alpha_i -1 >0$, and so $f$ is constant.

My problem is that I can't seem to come up with any example that satisfies this condition for all $x,y$.  Initially I guessed functions of the form $f(x) = \prod_{i=1}^n f_i(x_i)$ would work, but this doesn't fly.  For example, with $n=2$ we get
$$
f_1(x_1)f_2(x_2) - f_1(y_1) f_2(y_2) = (f_1(x_1) - f_1(y_1))f_2(x_2) + f_1(y_1)(f_2(x_2) - f_2(y_2))
$$
and so if $f_1,f_2$ are bounded and Holder continuous (with exponents $\alpha_1,\alpha_2$) we get 
$$
|f(x) - f(y)| \le C |x_1 - y_1|^{\alpha_1} + C |x_2 - y_2|^{\alpha_2}.
$$
This is not what we want.

Do such functions exist?  If so, is there a sufficient condition for generating them (something like the bounded derivative condition above)?  Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT:
@Dap made the observation I had overlooked.  If $x_i = y_i$ then $f(x)=f(y)$ and so $f$ must be constant on every hypersurface parallel to the coordinate axes.  This shows that $f$ is constant.

Comment: I don't know if this is useful but $\left(\sum_{j=1}^n \frac{\alpha_j}{x_j}\right)^{-1}\leq \prod_{j=1}^n x_j^{\alpha_j}\leq \sum_{j=1}^n \alpha_j x_j$ whenever $\alpha_1, \ldots, \alpha_n$ and $x_1, \ldots, x_n$ are positive and $\sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i=1$. In particular, $\displaystyle\frac{1}{\frac{1}{|x_1-y_1|^{\alpha_1}}+\ldots+ \frac{1}{|x_n-y_n|^{\alpha_n}}}\leq \prod_{j=1}^n |x_j-y_j|^{\alpha_j}$. Now you could try to find a function which is bounded by the left hand side..

Comment: They have to be constant on lines parallel to a co-ordinate axis, right? Any $x_i=y_i$ implies $f(x)=f(y).$

Comment: @Dap, yes you're right.  Actually, I think that shows all such $f$ are constants.  Thanks for the nice observation!

Comment: @Glitch just a petty remark : in your definition of Holder continuity between metric spaces, you take $\alpha \le 1$. You may (or not) have put this condition because '$\alpha$-Holder continuous functions for $\alpha>1$ are constant'. But this is false ! You can find a non constant $1.7$-Holder continuous function from a compact path-connected subset of the plane to $\mathbb{R}$. Then, I think your problem is still interesting : what if you consider a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ ?

Comment: @Glitch that is to say, considering the reciprocal point of view : does there exist a (continuous) function $f : x \in \mathbb{R} \mapsto \big(f_1(x), ..., f_n(x)\big) \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $C > 0$ such that for all $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$, $\prod \limits_{i=1}^n \big|f_i(x)-f_i(y)\big| \ge C |x-y|$ ?